# Problems to include test ads in android project

Tags: java, android

I am following [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start#load_the_ad_in_the_mainactivity_class) description to try to use test ads in my android project. However, the following two lines in the `main_activity.java` create the error 'Cannot resolve symbol ...':

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
```

Furthermore, a link on this page leads to [another page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/targeting#adrequest) explaining how to set up for test ads. The code is as follows:

```
AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)        // All emulators
    .addTestDevice("AC98C820A50B4AD8A2106EDE96FB87D4")  // An example device ID
    .build();
```

What is the device ID? Where do I find my device ID? Do I have to replace this code with the one given on the previous page for `main_activity.java`? Or do I misunderstand something?

So, how can I import `AdView` and `AdRequest`?

Comment: This seems like a build-path issue. Did you include Google Play Service? You need to add `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0' at the Project-level build.gradle and ` `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.0.0'` at the App-level build.gradle as well as - then right at the bottom of your App-level build.grandle file you add `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`. Hopefully this removes the error.

Comment: Yes it worked! So I guess the complicated tutorial on how to insert ads is outdated?

Comment: Great. I have extended my comment into answer - please vote and accept the answer if you find it helpful.

Comment: @Alex, the change to the integration is due to the recent (since last week) migration to Firebase.  You still have the option of using the SDK as a standalone product by importing the Google Play services via Gradle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a build-path issue. Did you include Google Play Service? You need to add classpath `com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0` at the Project-level `build.gradle` and compile `com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.0.0` at the App-level `build.gradle` as well as - then right at the bottom of your App-level build.grandle file you add `apply plugin: com.google.gms.google-services`. Hopefully this removes the error.

Then in terms of the rest of the adView code - you code seems OK. You can do something like this in your `Activity`:

```
mAdView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Where `R.id.adView` is defined in your layout file as:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"        
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="your-test-ad-uid-here">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Answer (score 0):

For removing the error if AdMob make sure you have compiled google play service in your gradle. And you can use

`.adTestDevice` as a optional one. Ads will also be shown without this

Comment: I am beginner in android, therefore I do not understand what you are trying to suggest...

Comment: ishmaeMakitla has told in the comment what I was trying to say

Comment: And you don't have to use the link .adTestDevice. Yoy can continue leaving this